# MacOS Bash Script using sed and grep doesn't work because of grep: repetition-operator operand invalid error

Tags: bash, sed, grep

I tried to update this line in `pubspec.yaml` on **macOS**

```
version: 0.2.6-alpha+26
```

```
#!/bin/bash


version=$(grep -oE '(?\<=version: )\[^ \]+' pubspec.yaml)

version=$(echo $version | sed 's/(\[0-9\].\[0-9\].\[0-9\])-alpha+(\[0-9\])/\\1-alpha+\\1/')

sed -i '' "s/version:.\*/version: $version/" pubspec.yaml
```

This script is intended to increment the patch number of the version number in the file pubspec.yaml. However, the script contains errors that cause it to throw the following error message:

```
grep: repetition-operator operand invalid
sed: 1: "s/([0-9].[0-9].[0-9])-a ...": \1 not defined in the RE
```

I'd like it to simply work

Comment: It'd help more if we knew how pubsec.yaml looked. Can't you just include the *version: ...* line in your question?

Comment: What do you expect from `(?` at the beginning of your regexp? And could you please show an example line of `pubspec.yaml` with the version number?

Comment: You may want `version=$(grep -oP '(?<=version: )\S+' pubspec.yaml)`.

Comment: @tshiono I might have missed to mention that the script should run on macOS

Comment: It looks like you're using the wrong versions of regex syntax. `grep -E` uses "extended" RE syntax, which doesn't support lookbehind assertions like `(?...)`. `sed` without `-E` uses "basic" RE syntax, where you need to escape parentheses to use them for grouping (the reverse of extended syntax). `sed -E` is almost always better. Also, you don't escape `[ ]` or `*` in *any* variant of RE syntax I've ever seen (well, unless you want them treated as plain characters).

Comment: You're probably looking for something like `sed -E 's/(version: ([0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])-alpha\+).*/\1\2/' pubspec.yaml` then

Comment: BTW, PCRE extensions are generally a bad idea; there are good reasons not to support them. Perl moved to a regex implementation that, while offering a bunch of shiny features, has _vastly_ slower worst-case performance than what was common before it, and tools adopting PCRE have generally also adopted those awful performance characteristics. See the Russ Cox paper on the topic at https://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/regexp1.html. (Granted, there are now hybrid engines implementing a subset of PCRE features without losing the advantages of the 1960s approaches)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your grep statement derives from [this bump_version.sh](https://gist.github.com/andyexeter/da932c9644d832e3be6706d20d539ff7#file-bump_version-sh-L48).

But the macOS `grep` does not recognize the GNU-grep `-P` option.
(Aside: The `?<=` syntax comes from Perl regular expressions.  See  "Lookbehind assertions" [here](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pcre2pattern.3.html).)

But you can drop the regex gymnastics by translating dots & dashes into spaces, which are easily digested by the Bash "read" command:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
grep version pubspec.yaml | (
IFS=' .-' read label major minor patch build;
sed -i '' "s/version:.*/version: $major.$minor.$((patch+1))-$build/" pubspec.yaml
)
```

Notes:

- This script favors piped output over variables & redirection.
- I didn't know that IFS can take multiple characters & applied C.Duffy's tip (to omit `tr`)!
- Reusing variables through Process Substitution is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: `read` can also digest dots and dashes just fine, if one uses `IFS=' .-' read -r label major minor patch build rest`. No reason to do gymnastics with `tr`.

Comment: BTW, I don't recommend favoring pipes. See [BashFAQ #24](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024) suggesting use of [process substitution](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/proc_subst) instead; that way variables can be set that last for the rest of the script.